# Cannot get data from API by passing parameters from form

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-forms

I have an API that gets data from API by passing parameters, but I can't pass the parameters to it from form:

- **My API :**

```
https://api.myapi.com/books?categor=[list of values]&creation_date=value
```

- **My interface:**

```
export interface Books{
    id: int
    name: string
    categor: string
    creation_date: string
}
```

- **My Service :**

```
import { Books } from '../interfaces/books ';

constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  getBooks(categor: string, creation_date: string): Observable<Books>{
    return this.http.get<Books>(`https://api.myapi.com/books?categor=${this.categor}&creation_date=${this.creation_date}`).pipe(
      tap(books=> console.log(books)),
    );
  }
```

- **My component.ts :**

```
books: any;
constructor(private booksService: BooksService){ }

onGetBooks(data:{categor: string, creation_date: string})
  {
    this.bookService.getBooks(data).subscribe((response) => {
      console.log(response);
      this.books = response.list;
    })
  }
```

- **My HTML code :**

```
<form #bookForm ="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onGetBooks(bookForm.value)">
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Input</mat-label>
    <input matInput name="categor" ngModel>
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Input</mat-label>
    <input matInput name="creation_date" ngModel>
  </mat-form-field>

  <button mat-raised-button>Get Books</button>

</form>
```

Comment: What do you mean you "can't pass the parameters"? You haven't shown how or where `onGetBooks` is called.

Comment: @WillAlexande , I get error when I pass the arguments

Answer (score 1):

You need to make couple of changes in you code

```
getBooks(categor: string, creation_date: string): Observable<Books>{
return this.http.get<Books>(`https://api.myapi.com/books?categor=${categor}&creation_date=${creation_date}`).pipe(
  tap(books=> console.log(books)),
);
}
```

In service file you don't need to use `this` as you are passing values to service file as the function arguments.

if you still face issue on calling API change,
either change tag `<button>` to `<input type="submit">`
or change event trigger of form (ngSubmit) to `<button>` to (click)

Comment: it's still passing `data`, so in the previous function call, arguments need to be destructured before: `onGetBooks({categor,creation_date} : {categor: string, creation_date: string}...` and then `this.bookService.getBooks(categor,creation_date)..`. or `data.` should be used..